# Is it appropriate to ask usability UX/UI questions here

Tags: discussion

I have a question about a website from field and its usability.

Is this an appropriate forum for that question?

The field contains functionality (A select dropdown which can toggle to free text input) so it's not purely design related.

Comment: That’s hard to say without knowing how much graphic design there is in your question. Or with other words: Why would you ask your question here instead of on [ux.se]?